# CSS style code is not showing up on my content class

Tags: html, css

```css
.post-container:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> My Blog </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div class="container">
      <a id="header-title" href="index.html">My Blog</a>
      <ul id="header-nav">
        <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="mailto:a@yahoo.com">Email Me</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="post-container">
      <div class="post">
        <div class="post-author">
          <img src="aj1.jpg">
          <span>Me</span>
        </div>
        <p class="post-date">Today</p>
        <h3 class="post-title"><em><strong>First Decent Looking Webpage</strong></em></h3>
        <div class="post-content">
          <p>This is all a test to see if everything is coming out ok.</p>
          <p>Just more random text to see how it all turns out</p>
          <p>Click <a href="https://www.youtube.com">here</a> for my favorite website!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="post-container">
      <div class="post">
        <div class="post-author">
          <img src="jim.jpg">
          <span>Jim</span>
        </div>
        <p class="post-date">Today</p>
        <h3 class="post-title"><em><strong>Trying to beat the Gold Challenge</strong></em></h3>
        <div class="post-content">
          <p>I think I <em>nailed</em> the gold challenge for this test.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I did a CSS, HTML tutorial using Mimo and after trying to complete one of the gold challenges I ran into an issue. I followed the steps to the tee and it won't work. There should be a color difference between the 2 blog posts that kind of will separate the posts on the website.

Comment: the `:nth-child` selector works for children that have the **same** parent. Your `.post-container`'s have different parents (which both have the same id `#content` which is invalid)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the same name as ID add a class to those divs and use that as the reference to get the `nth-child` like this

```css
.post:nth-child(even) .post-container {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> My Blog </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div class="container">
      <a id="header-title" href="index.html">My Blog</a>
      <ul id="header-nav">
        <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="mailto:a@yahoo.com">Email Me</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content" class="post">
    <div class="post-container">
      <div class="post">
        <div class="post-author">
          <img src="aj1.jpg">
          <span>Me</span>
        </div>
        <p class="post-date">Today</p>
        <h3 class="post-title"><em><strong>First Decent Looking Webpage</strong></em></h3>
        <div class="post-content">
          <p>This is all a test to see if everything is coming out ok.</p>
          <p>Just more random text to see how it all turns out</p>
          <p>Click <a href="https://www.youtube.com">here</a> for my favorite website!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content" class="post">
    <div class="post-container">
      <div class="post">
        <div class="post-author">
          <img src="jim.jpg">
          <span>Jim</span>
        </div>
        <p class="post-date">Today</p>
        <h3 class="post-title"><em><strong>Trying to beat the Gold Challenge</strong></em></h3>
        <div class="post-content">
          <p>I think I <em>nailed</em> the gold challenge for this test.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="column">
        <h4>My Links</h4>
        <p>
          <a href="">Facebook</a><br>
          <a href="">Instagram</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <h4>My Story</h4>
        <p>Hi There! I am an aspiring web developer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `nth-child` selector selects children of a common parent. Since your two `post-container` divs are not siblings, the `nth-child` counter never gets to 2 (the first even number). The simplest solution would be to target the `#content` divs, since they're siblings, however you have a problem with your markup in that you reuse the `content` `id` (`id`s must be unique!). I've changed the divs to have the **class** of `content` instead of `id`, and modified the css accordingly. Now the second post has a gray background, as desired:

```css
.content:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> My Blog </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div class="container">
      <a id="header-title" href="index.html">My Blog</a>
      <ul id="header-nav">
        <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="mailto:a@yahoo.com">Email Me</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="post-container">
      <div class="post">
        <div class="post-author">
          <img src="aj1.jpg">
          <span>Me</span>
        </div>
        <p class="post-date">Today</p>
        <h3 class="post-title"><em><strong>First Decent Looking Webpage</strong></em></h3>
        <div class="post-content">
          <p>This is all a test to see if everything is coming out ok.</p>
          <p>Just more random text to see how it all turns out</p>
          <p>Click <a href="https://www.youtube.com">here</a> for my favorite website!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="post-container">
      <div class="post">
        <div class="post-author">
          <img src="jim.jpg">
          <span>Jim</span>
        </div>
        <p class="post-date">Today</p>
        <h3 class="post-title"><em><strong>Trying to beat the Gold Challenge</strong></em></h3>
        <div class="post-content">
          <p>I think I <em>nailed</em> the gold challenge for this test.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="column">
        <h4>My Links</h4>
        <p>
          <a href="">Facebook</a><br>
          <a href="">Instagram</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <h4>My Story</h4>
        <p>Hi There! I am an aspiring web developer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you! How would I get the bottom portion to be a different color instead of the top?

Comment: Perhaps change `nth-child(even)` to `nth-child(odd)`.